# Confusion in the calculation of the Free Energy in a Fuel Cell

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, entropy, hydrogen

I am writing a thesis about fuel cells and trying to follow the calcultion of the Gibbs free enery of the reaction of some author. I am confused because he took the higher heating value (HHV) of the hydrogen, which means that the water is in liquid form, but then continued the calculation with the standard entropy of water when it's in gasform. This is his calculation:

The reaction in the fuel cell is given through:
$$ H_2 + \frac{1}{2}O_2 \rightarrow H_2O $$

The free energy could be calculated through Gibbs-Helmholz equation:
$$\Delta G = H-T\Delta S$$

The author took the HHV of hydrogen, which means that the water created in the reaction is in liquid form. We get $H^{HHV} = -286\frac{kJ}{mol}$. Next he calculated the standard entropy by summing the standard entropy of both sides of the reaction, and then calculating the total standard entropy of reacton through:
$$\Delta S^° = \sum_{products}\Delta S^° - \sum_{reactans}\Delta S^° = \Delta S^°_{H_2O} - \Delta S^°_{H_2} - \Delta S^°_{O_2}$$
However, I am now confused. For the calculation he took $\Delta S^°_{H_2O} = 188.8\frac{J}{mol}$, which describes water in vapor state ([reference](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C7732185&Units=SI&Mask=1#Thermo-Gas)). Isn't that a contradiction? How can he assume that water is in liquid form (due to the usage of the HHV), but then take the standard entropy of water vapor? shouldn't he take the value $\Delta S^°_{H_2O} = 69.9\frac{J}{mol}$ ([reference](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C7732185&Units=SI&Mask=2#Thermo-Condensed)) that describes water in liquid state?

This calculation leads to the maximal theoretical efficiency of the fuel cell, $84$%. Since all authors take this value I assume that it is me who misses something here. For clarity I continue the calculation:

| Molecule | Standard Entropy in $\frac{J}{molK}$ |

| $H_2 $| 130.6 |

| $O_2 $| 205.1 |

| $H_2O (g) $| 188.8 |

| $H_2O (l) $| 69.9|

With this we get:
$S^°(H_2O(g)) = 147\frac{J}{molK}$ and $S^°(H_2O(l)) = 266\frac{J}{molK}$

The temperature is $T=25°C = 298.15K$.

By substituting it all in the Gibbs-Helmholz equation we get: $G(S^°(H_2O(g))) = -241\frac{kJ}{mol}$ and $G(S^°(H_2O(l))) = 206.5\frac{J}{molK}$. Again, $G$ was caluclated by using the HHV. I looked in around 10 references and they all claim that the theoretical efficincy of a fuel cell is $84$%. They calculate it through:
$$\eta = \frac{G(S^°(H_2O(g)))}{H} = \frac{-241\frac{kJ}{mol}}{-286\frac{kJ}{mol}} = 84\%$$

I'd be grateful for your help.

Comment: Well, he should certainly remain consistent.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be posted in chemistry.stackexchange. com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Handbook of chemistry, you can find directly the standard enthalpy and Gibbs free energy of formation of liquid water :
$\Delta_f H° = -285.8 KJ/mol$ and $\Delta_f G° = -237.1 KJ/mol$

So $\Delta_f G°/\Delta_f H°=237.1/285.8 = 0.83 $ as expected.

I did not redo your calculations but in what you give the sign of the standard entropies is not correct: it must be positive.

Edit :

When I compute the standard entropy of formation with your values, I find, with $S° = 70 j/mol/K $ for liquid water :
$\Delta_r S°= 70-130.6-0.5*205.1=-163.15 j/mol/K$
And $\Delta_r G°(298) = -285.8 +163.15*298 = -237 KJ/mol$ as expected.

Maybe your formula for $\Delta_r S°$ is not correct ?

Comment: About the minux sign, you are right. I accidently multiplied it with -1 because the water is in the product side. The value is correct, but then we just need to sum (and not substract) all standard entropy to get the standard entropy of reaction. Thank you for that, I corrected my post. About the Gibbs free energy: yes, I have seen this value many times, but I don't understand how this value is derived. The authors that actually derive it use only the inconsistent method I described in my post.

Comment: I completed the answer. Hope it can help !

Comment: Yes, this is correct and consistent with a standard entropy change of -163 J/mole K

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to multiply the standard entropy of oxygen with 0.5. This value is approximatly the same as the difference of the standard entropy of liquid water and water vapor, which created the confusion.